# Increase the maximum request length in a Azure Api App

Tags: c#, api, azure, file-upload, azure-api-apps

I have created an Azure Api App which I will use to upload files. These files will be > 4mb hence the need to increase the maximum request length. I have added the following to Web.config:

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="7200" targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097152" />
  </system.web>
```

I have also added:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2097152000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Yet I still get the exception `Maximum request length exceeded.`. Am I missing something? Is there something else I can try?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `<system.web>` section setting is still 2 MB whereas in `<system.webServer>` it is 200 MB.

Comment: @GauravMantri `maxRequestLength` is in kilobytes and `maxAllowedContentLength` is in bytes.

Comment: Can you share your approach for uploading files using an API App? I'm namely looking for a way to hopefully best utilize Swagger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible yet. Except the limitation on the API App, there is also a limitation on the Gateway which is an ASP.NET app as well. You can change your API App but you cannot change the Gateway.

I know the team is looking into providing a solution to that but I don't have an ETA to share at this point.