# Azure gateway app host: adjust maximum request length

Tags: .net, azure, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to upload big files to my Web API app hosted on Azure. Both `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` are set for ~60 MBs. Upload works locally and on our test app services on Azure.
However, after uploading to production, I've found out that upload for ~35MBs file does not work.

After some investigation, I found the following links:
[Increase the maximum request length in a Azure Api App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339416/increase-the-maximum-request-length-in-a-azure-api-app)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b5dbab38-9741-45ca-a791-1847b2935bb0/azure-api-app-rest-web-api-upload-limit?forum=AzureAPIApps

They say that the issue is that Gateway app host (which is used on our Production server as well) does not pass these big requests. The answers there are pretty old, so I thought that something has changed since then.

I tried to change request length parameters in Web.config file in wwroot directory of the gateway using Kudu console, but still have the same result.

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the request size for Azure Gateway app host now, or is it still impossible?

Comment: I have got an active ticket about it, I'll report back here on it's outcome

Comment: Hi Tom, please let me know if the support provided any answer. If not, please see my comment below. It explains how we managed to resolve the issue on our project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is not an exact answer, but still a way to resolve the issue.

One of my colleagues found out that Azure gateway is implemented as a web service extension. We do not have rights to edit its config, that's why we cannot change the maximum request length.

But what he did is created a copy of this web extension on the same machine and pointed Azure Gateway Host to it. As this new web extension was created by us, we now can change the request length.